# Vaadin hilla property call does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, hilla

I was trying to create a vaadin hilla application, trying to save a person's details. Created endpoint and the person object as well, but in generated files, the error is showing as below.

> [TypeScript] Property 'call' does not exist on type 'PersonDetails'.

The application is running, pages also came up but with error.

```
@Endpoint
@AnonymousAllowed
public class PersonEndpoint {

    private InterPersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonEndpoint(InterPersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String savePerson(PersonDetails person) {
        return this.personService.savePerson(person);
    }

}
```

Vaadin hilla application to save a person's details. Expected to set the value from the textbox to the generated object and the data will be available in the endpoint save method.

Comment: Try re-running the app, it sounds like something in the frontend compilation hasn't worked the way it should